# Running Totals with Filters in MDX?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx, measure, cumulative-sum

I want to start running-total from the date I choose in filter in Power BI, because all functions MDX I have tried, start running-total from the first value.

Like in the image I have shared I want running-total of SUM column start from the date i choose in filter.

My Dashbord in Power BI is connected to a OLAP Cube SSAS (Data source).

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's MDX? I have always though that Power BI uses DAX.

Comment: Sorry I forget to specific, my Dashboard have as data source a OLAP Cube SSAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that in your running total you are summing the values without context.

Take a look at the example

```
with 
member 
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = null then null 
else 
sum( {[Date].[Calendar Year].firstchild:[Date].[Calendar Year].currentmember},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
end

select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
} on columns,

non empty
([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year])
on 
rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result 
[image]

Now lets make some changes

```
with 
member 
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = null then null 
else 
sum(existing {[Date].[Calendar Year].firstchild:[Date].[Calendar Year].currentmember},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])  
end 

select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
} on columns,

non empty
([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year])
on 
rows 
from 
(select[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012]:[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013] on 0 from [Adventure Works] )
```

Result

[image]

Notice that in the second result the values for years before 2012 were not included. This all happens becuse of the use of "existing" keyword which ensure the expression is evaluated within context.